# Get Local timezone from specific zone

Tags: angular, luxon

I currently use Luxon with the following code:

```
this.now = DateTime.local();
```

However, I'd like to get the current time from another timezone like 'Europe/London'. Is this possible in Luxon?

Something like this:

```
this.now = DateTime.local('Europe/London');
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`setZone`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimesetzone) method that:

> "Set" the DateTime's zone to specified zone. Returns a newly-constructed DateTime.

or you can use [`fromObject`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromobject) specifying `zone` property as suggested by snickersnack in the comments.

Here a live sample:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const now = DateTime.local().setZone('Europe/London');
console.log( now.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_FULL) );

// Using fromObject as suggested by snickersnack
const nowObj = DateTime.fromObject({ zone: 'Europe/London' });
console.log( nowObj.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_FULL) );
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

See also [Creating DateTimes in a zone](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/zones?id=creating-datetimes-in-a-zone) section of the manual.

Comment: It's not well documented, but you can also do `DateTime.fromObject({ zone: "Europe/London" })`

Comment: @snickersnack you are right, thank you for the comment. I've edited my answer to include the `fromObject` solution.